# how to install libevent on eclipse c/c++

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04, libevent

I am trying and using libevent in my eclipse c/c++ project.
I downloaded the libevent library using this command

```
 sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```

It is working normally so that in the specific directory
I was looking for a **libevent.a** file to include it as library in my eclipse project but I can only find a **libevent.la**

How can I use it in this case? 
I am using ubuntu 12.04 and eclipse Version: Kepler Release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you see it with command:

```
dpkg -L libevent-dev|grep libevent.a
```

In normally, libevent-dev will install libevent to standard system library location, so you just need to add `event` to Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Path And Symbols -> Library Paths